# Jenkins builds to use Android manifest versionName tag

Tags: android, jenkins, build

I need to use the versionName tag from the AndroidManifest.xml file in jenkins builds.
For now, i change the jenkins release version manually, when the android version changes, for example: 1.2.1:${BUILD_NUMBER}. I want to use the versionName tag from the manifest file instead of the hardcoded 1.2.1. 
Is there a way i can do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What configuration have you tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't find any useful information, i'm relatively new to jenkins, so i would really appreciate any advice.